# Sending two request for a 404 file

Tags: javascript, firebug, http-status-code-404, httprequest

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="empty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="no-file"></script>
<?php highlight_file(__FILE__); ?>
```

The page can be viewed in browser as given below.
[image]
The firebug says that they send two request for the file "no-file".

I just removed the first script-tag. That time, they are sending only one request for the "no-file"
why are they sending two request for a 404 file?

NB: There is no file with the name "no-file" in my system and the "empty.js" is an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good reason for it, other than it being a bug. More details here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648568